# Getting an error -Sencha touch 2 and Cordova 1.6.1

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, cordova

I have copied the WWW folder off https://github.com/senchalearn/phonegapcontacts/tree/1_basic_structure , and now i am unable to run the application. (I just get a blank screen that can be scrolled)

But, when i edit the `app.js`, a white screen appears but it stays static.

I have changed `Ext.regApplication`  to `Ext.application`, and i get the white static screen and the following error

> [INFO] Error in success callback: NetworkStatus0 = ReferenceError:
>   Can't find variable: views

my `app.js` file is as follows.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        this.launched = true;
        this.mainLaunch();
    },
                launch: function() {                                            
                this.view.ViewPort = new this.view.Viewport();
                }
});
```

Google suggest that there might be a method used in the app.js that is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure but this line at this.ViewPort = new gives me a sense that your views are not rendered properly.

Comment: Sorry that line should be this.view.ViewPort = new this.view.Viewport(); i have edited the code

Comment: And do you know why this is occurring `I have changed Ext.regApplication to Ext.application, and i get the white static screen and the following error` ?

Comment: It's reponsible to create application object. It's some thing  similar to ext.setup. Well I have worked on extjs and touch is slightly diffeent with it's configuration